# List variables names in one column

Tags: list, variables, stata

Is there a way to obtain a long list of variables (one per line) instead of the wide paragraph with multiple columns? The goal is to simplify the copy and paste with one variable per line.

Example data:

```
clear

input Var1-Var25
1.1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0  
2.1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0   
3.1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0  
4.1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0  
5.1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
end
```

It seems the options of `ds` do not help; the maximum `varwidth(32)` yields too many columns, while the `indent(#)` may create one column but leaves spaces in front.

For example:

```
ds, varwidth(32)
Var1   Var2   Var3   Var4   Var5   Var6   Var7   Var8   Var9   Var10  Var11  Var12  Var13  Var14  Var15  Var16  Var17  Var18  Var19  Var20  Var21  Var22  Var23  Var24  Var25


ds, indent(20)
                    Var1   Var2   Var3   Var4   Var5   Var6   Var7   Var8   Var9   Var10  Var11  Var12  Var13  Var14  Var15  Var16  Var17  Var18  Var19  Var20  Var21  Var22  Var23  Var24  Var25
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
ds
local vars = r(varlist)

foreach x of varlist `vars' {
    display " `x' "
}

 Var1 
 Var2 
 Var3 
 Var4 
 Var5 
 Var6 
 Var7 
 Var8 
 Var9 
 Var10 
 Var11 
 Var12 
 Var13 
 Var14 
 Var15 
 Var16 
 Var17 
 Var18 
 Var19 
 Var20 
 Var21 
 Var22 
 Var23 
 Var24 
 Var25
```

Comment: You can just loop over a _varlist_ *. No need for anything earlier.